# Why is it not required to use typename for dependent types in the following case?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-traits, dependent-name

I have been reading about removing reference of a type, [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference).

It gives the following example:

```
#include <iostream> // std::cout
#include <type_traits> // std::is_same

template<class T1, class T2>
void print_is_same() {
  std::cout << std::is_same<T1, T2>() << '\n';
}

int main() {
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;

  print_is_same<int, int>();
  print_is_same<int, int &>();
  print_is_same<int, int &&>();

  print_is_same<int, std::remove_reference<int>::type>(); // Why not typename std::remove_reference<int>::type ?
  print_is_same<int, std::remove_reference<int &>::type>();// Why not typename std::remove_reference<int &>::type ?
  print_is_same<int, std::remove_reference<int &&>::type>();// Why not typename std::remove_reference<int &&>::type ?
}
```

The `type`s in the `std::remove_reference` traits are dependent types.

**Possible implementation**

```
template< class T > struct remove_reference      {typedef T type;};
template< class T > struct remove_reference<T&>  {typedef T type;};
template< class T > struct remove_reference<T&&> {typedef T type;};
```

But why does it not use `typename std::remove_reference</*TYPE*/>::type`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> The `type`s in the `std::remove_reference` traits are dependent types.

No, they are not [dependent names](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) here. The template arguments have been specified explicitly as `int`, `int&` and `int&&`. Therefore, the types are known at this point.

On the other hand, if you use `std::remove_reference` with a template parameter, e.g.

```
template <typename T>
void foo() {
    print_is_same<int, typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>();
}
```

then you have to use [`typename`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/typename) to tell that `std::remove_reference<T>::type` is a type as your expression now depends on the template parameter `T`.

Answer (score 4):

In a nutshell, you need `typename` to ensure the compiler that

```
std::remove_reference<int>::type
```

really is a type. Lets consider some other template

```
template <typename T>
struct foo {
    using type = int;
};
```

Here `foo::type` is a type. But what if someone supplies a specialization along the line of

```
template <> struct foo<int> {
    int type;
};
```

Now `type` is not a type but an `int`. Now when you use foo inside a template:

```
template <typanem T> 
struct bar {
    using type = typename foo<T>::type;
};
```

You have to ensure the compiler that `foo<T>::type` really is a type, not something else, because only looking at `bar` (and the primary template `foo`) the compiler cannot know that.

However, in your `main` the `std::remove_reference<int>::type` does not depend on a template parameter, hence the compiler can readily check if it is a type.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword **typename** is used to help compiler parse the source. 
It points the id is a type name, not a variable name or method name. 
But in situations like above compiler can figure out it itself, so this keyword is not required.

Comment: This is not true.see the other answers